# grunt build ng-annotate error

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, requirejs, bower

I am trying to build my angularjs app using Grunt, but it seems that ng-annotate is hung up. I am using npm version 2.6.0 and have done `npm install --save-dev` and `npm install -g` and also tried to update my ng-annotate and grunt-ng-annotate references as well as update all my bower packages. Anyone run into this error (below)?

grunt build command:

```
$ grunt build
Running "clean:dist" (clean) task
Cleaning .tmp...OK

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task

Running "bower:app" (bower) task
Updated RequireJS config with installed Bower components

Running "replace:test" (replace) task

Running "useminPrepare:html" (useminPrepare) task
Configuration changed for concat, uglify, cssmin

Running "concurrent:dist" (concurrent) task

Running "svgmin:dist" (svgmin) task
Total saved: 0 B

Done, without errors.

Running "copy:styles" (copy) task
Copied 1 files

Done, without errors.

Running "imagemin:dist" (imagemin) task
Minified 0 images (saved 0 B)

Done, without errors.

Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task
File .tmp/styles/main.css created.

Running "concat:generated" (concat) task
File .tmp\concat\styles\vendor.css created.
File .tmp\concat\styles\main.css created.

Running "ngAnnotate:dist" (ngAnnotate) task
Generating ".tmp/analyst_workbench/bower_components/jquery/src/intro.js" from: "
my_app_name/bower_components/jquery/src/intro.js"...ERROR
>> error: couldn't process source due to parse error
>> Unexpected token (45:0)
Generating ".tmp/analyst_workbench/bower_components/jquery/src/outro.js" from: "
my_app_name/bower_components/jquery/src/outro.js"...ERROR
>> error: couldn't process source due to parse error
>> Unexpected token (1:0)
Warning: Task "ngAnnotate:dist" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2015-02-23 16:31:18 UTC)
clean:dist       172ms  ■ 1%
wiredep:app      273ms  ■ 2%
bower:app         1.3s  ■■■■ 8%
concurrent:dist   9.8s  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 66%
ngAnnotate:dist   3.3s  ■■■■■■■■■■ 22%
Total 14.9s
```

Grunt.js ng-annotate portion:

```
// ng-annotate tries to make the code safe for minification automatically
    // by using the Angular long form for dependency injection.
    ngAnnotate: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          //cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/<%= yeoman.components %>',
          src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/<%= yeoman.components %>/**/*.js', '!<%= yeoman.app %>/<%= yeoman.components %>/oldieshim.js'],
          dest: '.tmp'
        }]
      }
    },
```

**EDIT:** Olov answered my question here. https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate/issues/143